# Laravel:Page is expired

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I made a contact field, but when I click on the submit, I got a white screen with "The page has expired due to inactivity. Please refresh and try again." message.

The form:

```
 <form action="/" method="post">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="name">
                                            Név</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Név" required="required" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="phone">
                                            Telefonszám</label>
                                        <div class="input-group">
                                            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="fa fa-phone "></span>
                                            </span>
                                            <input type="phone" class="form-control" id="phone" placeholder="Telefonszám" required="required" /></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="email">
                                            E-mail cím</label>
                                        <div class="input-group">
                                            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="fa fa-envelope"></span>
                                            </span>
                                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="E-mail cím" required="required" /></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="subject">
                                            Tárgy</label>
                                        <select id="subject" name="subject" class="form-control" required="required">
                                            <option value="na" selected="">:: Tárgy:: </option>
                                            <option value="contact">Kapcsolat</option>
                                            <option value="pricequote">Árajánlat</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="name">
                                            Üzenet</label>
                                        <textarea name="message" id="message" class="form-control" rows="13" cols="25" required="required"
                                            placeholder="Üzenet"></textarea>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" id="btnContactUs">
                                        Üzenet küldése</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
```

And I have a `Route::post('/', 'Controller@Action');`

What is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you missed the CSRF token. Take a look here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/csrf#csrf-introduction

You only need to add the token in your form. Something like this:

```
<form action="/" method="post">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    ... 
</form>
```

I hope it works fine for you.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's because you missed the CSRF token in your form. If you are using Blade, then you can add it like this:

```
{{ csrf_field() }}
```

Or you can disable the `VerifyCsrfToken` middleware (which I do not recommend).

View more on the [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/csrf).